# Postfix mailfilter working for incoming mail on port 25 but not on 587

Tags: postfix, smtp

This seems like a simple task, but I can't find out how to do it.

I have configured a postfix mailfilter to process every incoming email delivered via SMTP on port 25 according to the [Simple Filter Example in the postfix docs](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#simple_filter).

So the in `master.cf`, I have added

```
filter   unix  -       n       n       -       5       pipe
  flags=Rq user=mailfilter null_sender=
  argv=/opt/custom/postfix/myfilterscript.sh -f ${sender} -- ${recipient}
```

The service configuration looks like this:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen  
smtpd     pass  -       -       n       -       -       smtpd 
  -o content_filter=filter:dummy
dnsblog   unix  -       -       n       -       0       dnsblog
tlsproxy  unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
```

I suspect the problem is here, but I can't find out how to enable filtering for incoming email on port 587. I'm not familiar with postfix configuration, and I seem to be unable to find an explanation in the docs.

So what do I have to change to make postfix use the same mailfilter for port 587 as it does for port 25?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is so simple:

```
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o content_filter=filter:dummy
```

However, I've had a hard time to understand the meaning of the service_name and service_type entries. [The manual](https://www.postfix.org/master.5.html) is not very helpful IMHO, because it says

> The  service name is specified as host:port, denoting the host  and  port  on  which  new  connections  should   be accepted.  The  host  part  (and  colon)  may be omitted.

With this explanation, the reader keeps wondering what the existing entries mean, as one would now expect numeric ports here. While it mentioned that `smtp` stands for received mail somehow, the details remain a mystery, and there's no reference to some other place in the docs that would help to shed some light on it.

I finally suspected that `smtp` stands for port 25, while `submission` stands for port 587, so I added the `-o content_filter=filter:dummy` parameter to the `submission` entry as well. Seems my assumption was correct, as it works now.

Still wondering where this is defined or described though.

Comment: If it helps, the mapping `submission` →port 587 can be found in `/etc/services`. See `man services`.

Comment: The next line after your quote is a pointer, referencing `services(5)` is meant to tell you that you can read `man 5 services` for further details on the symbolic  form. Some programs for reading man pages will expect the reader to just know this, others make the reference work as you would expect in a modern web browser.

Comment: @anx Thanks for the pointer. I had found the `known_tcp_ports` configuration keyword in the [Postfix main.cf file format reference](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html), but it doesn't appear anywhere in my own `main.cf`. It is described as an _optional setting that avoids lookups in the services(5) database_, but I did not know how to find the corresponding reference manual. Seems to be one of the things that go without saying when using Linux...

Comment: Better use plain numbers they always clear